# custom jsf components with a4j support

Tags: ajax, jsf, components, ajax4jsf

Does anyone can tell me about some good tutorial related on building custom jsf components with ajax capabilities with a4j?
best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit older already, but this is a nice start: http://demetrio812.blogspot.com/2007/10/creating-jsf-component-using-richfaces.html

Also the richfaces guide is good background material. But there is not much about custom components there. http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/index.html